# issues to list the "command prompt" profile in the vs code terminal under a tunel conecction from mac to windows

Tags: vscode-remote

I recently started to use the VS Code tunnel extension to connect my vs code from mac to a Windows pc. Everything works as I expected except that when I open a new terminal, I can not select in the profiles the Command Prompt. The Command Prompt is not listed in the profiles availabe. The configuration of the profiles for windows in vs code is :

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        }
```

I would like to know if there is something wrong, or I need to do something else , the Git Bash and the PowerShell works perfectly
Thanks in advance